# Using Managed Navigation will display “Page not found” error when clicking on its links

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, navigation, managed-metadata, managed-navigation

I have an enterprise wiki library site collection, and for the navigation I define to use a Managed Navigation as follow:-

[image]

But currently when users click on the left side managed navigation they will get the following error :-

[image]

So I have the following questions:-

1. How I can solve the “Page not found” error?
2. Is there a way to control the hierarchy level, currently only two levels is going to be displayed?
3. Is there a way to improve the look & feel  for the managed navigation to be something similar to the MSDN left side navigation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms123401.aspx ?
   Thanks

**Edit**

After checking further on this , and checking the “Term driven Page” inside the metadata service, I found that my problem is divided into two parts:-

1. If I have a main Term containing a space such as “Software Engineering”, then clicking on this term inside the left navigation will add “-” instead of the space so the result URL will be `/software-engineering` instead of `/software engineering`
2. Second problem clicking on a child term should display all the Wiki pages that are tagged with this specific term. while clicking on a term inside the left navigation will generate the following URL which will display “page not found” :-

> /Software-engineering/intranet

While clicking on the term inside the Category column will generate this URL which will show all the related Wikis:-

```
SoftwareEngineering/_layouts/15/Categories.aspx?FieldName=Wiki_x0020_Page_x0020_Categories&FieldValue=66383f35-0543-4424-adce-d268c3e0246f&ListId=3f905a06-8521-4454-9841-99a1f5fa696a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you look at the properties for the term, is it pointing to a page that exists? if you look at the "Target Page for this term" setting in the "Term-Driven Pages" tab you should see it pointing to an actual aspx page. Try to navigate to this page using the full /pages/page.aspx url.
2. I believe the out of the box control used for Quick Links navigation allows two levels of links to be displayed by default. To display more levels you'll need to update the MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels property on the quick launch menu control in the master page. 
   Example:
   `<SharePoint:AspMenu id="V4QuickLaunchMenu" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" DataSourceId="QuickLaunchSiteMap" UseSimpleRendering="true" Orientation="Vertical" StaticDisplayLevels="1" AdjustForShowStartingNode="true" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="3" SkipLinkText="" />`
3. You can probably simulate a good deal of that navigation styling using just CSS and overriding the OOB styles.

**Edit: More answers**

1. managed navigation always replaces spaces in the term label with '-'. This is standard SEO friendly behavior. You can force it to use something else (also found in the Term-Driven Pages tab), but I would recommend not using spaces in your URLs.
2. Sounds to me like you should create a new page that utilizes the [Catalog Item Reuse Web Part](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/inconvenient-catalog-item-reuse-web-part-displaying-content-managed-properties/) in combination with a content by search web part to display a roll-up of wiki articles tagged with your term. Then you would reference this page in the Target page for the children (can't remember the exact name), also in the "Term-Driven Pages" tab.

Comment: thansk for the reply,, i checked the Term-Driven Pages ,, can you check my edit ..